# Bootstrap Datetime picker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I want to add Bootstrap DateTime picker to my webpage but it did not work.in my Bootstrap folder I created test.html and added wrote following code inside:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script   src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">  </script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class='col-sm-6'>
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
             $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").FUNCTION()
          });
       </script>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have any built-in datetime picker as far I know so it seems you're missing a library. Where did you get this code?

Comment: Claudio Redi ,I got that code from  this link from here: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install bootstrap datepicker from this [link](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/)

it will be looking like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
```

and

```
  <script
src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js">
```

like this in your header

Comment: That worked.Thank you very much  Prabhu Vignesh Rajagopa

Comment: Much to my regrets, I do not have enough reputation , therefore can not do right now.will mark as accepted  as soon as being able.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does not have any DateTime picker out of the box, you must use third party libraries like [jquery-ui Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).